# How pause and then resume a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I state that I read about thread, but I've never used.
So I ask to you :)

I have two thread: `A` and `B`, 
where `A` manages the GUI, and `B` manages the logic.

I would start with `A`.

Then when `A` draw the GUI, I would pause it, to wait `B` that reach a point X into run method.

And when `B` reach the X point into run method, I pause `B`, and resume `A`.

`A` and `B` share some variable to manage the GUI, and the logic...

Can I do it? if yes, how? :)

Comment: Yes, you can do it. This is a basic Threads exercise. Try to do it, if you fail, we're here to help :)

Comment: The entire idea behind having multiple threads is that you don't have to explicitly pause/yield/etc with them, by having multiple threads running concurrently they will be given slices of CPU time in a fair, balanced manner. (In particular, you should try to never pause the GUI thread, so that the GUI is always responsive) Yes, you can do it, but I don't think you need to.

Comment: Just a side note. Swing is a single threaded environment, meaning that all interactions and modifications to any of the UI elements must be made with the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Swing is not thread safe, meaning you should never try and access, updates or create any UI elements from any thread other then the EDT...assume your using Swing that is

Comment: I don't suggest your make your GUI wait for the thread, I suggest that you simply start the thread, when the thread finish, it should do a callback so that the GUI will do the logic that depends on that thread .. because if you make your whole GUI wait, it will freeze while the thread is working in the background

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) and [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) methods:

> **`wait()`** - Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object.
>
> **`notify()`** - Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.

Comment: I would recommend a `Semaphore` as the avoids the common pitfalls in `synchronized` and `wait`/`notify`.

Comment: [In this official article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) you can find snippets of how to use `wait()` and `notify()` correctly and why the original `suspend()` and `resume()` methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 28):

You can block threads using the `wait` and `notify` methods of the Object class, but it can be tricky to get right.  Here's an example inside an infinite loop in a Runnable:

```java
public class Example implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running = true;
    private volatile boolean paused = false;
    private final Object pauseLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            synchronized (pauseLock) {
                if (!running) { // may have changed while waiting to
                    // synchronize on pauseLock
                    break;
                }
                if (paused) {
                    try {
                        pauseLock.wait(); // will cause this Thread to block until 
                        // another thread calls pauseLock.notifyAll()
                        // Note that calling wait() will 
                        // relinquish the synchronized lock that this 
                        // thread holds on pauseLock so another thread
                        // can acquire the lock to call notifyAll()
                        // (link with explanation below this code)
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (!running) { // running might have changed since we paused
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Your code here
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        // you might also want to interrupt() the Thread that is 
        // running this Runnable, too, or perhaps call:
        resume();
        // to unblock
    }

    public void pause() {
        // you may want to throw an IllegalStateException if !running
        paused = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        synchronized (pauseLock) {
            paused = false;
            pauseLock.notifyAll(); // Unblocks thread
        }
    }
};
```

(For more information on why we need to synchronize as illustrated above whilst calling `wait` and `notifyAll`, see [the Java tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).)

If another Thread calls this Runnable's `pause()` method, then the Thread running the runnable will block when it gets to the top of the while loop.

Note that it is not possible to pause a thread at any arbitrary point.  You need the Thread to periodically check whether it should pause and block itself if so.

Comment: You have synchronized with pauseLock, the resume method, so the wait will never be notified, the above will deadlock

Comment: @DrBDOAdams `wait` and `notify` must **always** be called in a `synchronized` block.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). Indeed, an `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown if you try otherwise.  Note that when `wait()` is called, the current thread will relinquish the lock it holds on that object allowing other threads to acquire it.

Comment: Calling `interrupt();` (or even `Thread.interrupt();`) seems wrong, as this class does not extend `Thread`.  Should that be a call to `resume();` instead?

Comment: @JesseChisholm Good spot - I've amended.

Comment: Your nested `synchronized (pauseLock)` blocks don't make sense.

Comment: @Robert yes, the inner one is redundant, I've removed it.

Answer (score 4):

I would expect that you don't need to pause the GUI thread.  The operating system will take care of that, and it needs to be ready to respond in case the user does something.

One other thought is to make sure the shared variables are properly synchronized between the two threads. I tried answering a question relating to that recently, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649216/how-to-handle-variables-shared-between-ui-thread-and-another-thread-in-android/16649455#16649455).

Answer (score 4):

you can use a `CountDownLatch`. When Thread A has to wait for Thread B will call `countDownLatchInstance.await();` When B reach the X point will invoke `countDownLatchInstance.countDown()`; allowing A to continue  its execution flow.

When you say

> A manages the GUI

I hope you do not refer to the `UI/Main Thread`

,

Comment: Personally I would recommend a `Semaphore` rather than a `CountDownLatch` as the `CountDownLatch` cannot be reused...

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Mutex {
    private final AtomicBoolean lock;
    private final Object mutex;

    public Mutex(boolean lock) {
        this.lock = new AtomicBoolean(lock);
        this.mutex = new Object();
    }

    public void step() {
        if (lock.get()) synchronized(mutex) {
            try {
                mutex.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    public void lock() {
        lock.set(true);
    }

    public void unlock() {
        lock.set(false);

        synchronized(mutex) {
            mutex.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Just add Mutex object to your thread and make getter.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final Mutex mutex;

    public MyThread() {
        this.mutex = new Mutex(false);
    }

    public Mutex getMutex() {
        return this.mutex;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            mutex.step();

            // do your code
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pause the thread just call

```
myThread.getMutex().lock();
```

If you want to resume the thread just call

```
myThread.getMutex().unlock();
```

Comment: Works //do you code is not need to be loop in any kind it will run till the loop finish

Answer (score 2):

That's the way I got thread's wait and notify working for me:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Object lock = new Object();


        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        t.lock = lock;
        t.run();

        while (true) {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
                System.out.println("hello");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    Object lock;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Anothing");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Next");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notify();
                }

            }
        });
        fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        fr.add(btn);
        fr.setSize(400, 400);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then, whenever I press the button, the other thread wakes up, executes one round and waits for a new clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The java primitive to suspend and resume a thread is deprecated. See this to figure how you can achieve best what you need - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
Check how you can do the equivalent of suspend & resume

> What should I use instead of `Thread.suspend` and `Thread.resume`?
>
> As with `Thread.stop`, the prudent approach is to have the "target thread" poll a variable indicating the desired state of the thread (active or suspended). When the desired state is suspended, the thread waits using `Object.wait`. When the thread is resumed, the target thread is notified using `Object.notify`.

Example code is given in the same answer to help you achieve this.