# Using Runnable Class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a `Class` which implements `Runnable`. I am using this Class in a thread and am trying to pause it and then restart it again using some sort of a `boolean` flag. This is my code:

```
class pushFiles implements Runnable{    
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void run () {
        .
        .  some code
        .
        while (running){
            .
            .  more code
            .
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        running = true;
    }
};
```

I am trying to pause the thread using the `stop` method and restart it using the `start` method.

The `stop` method actually stops/pauses the thread, but the `start` method does not make it run again.

When initializing the thread I use:

```
runnable = new pushFiles();
thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to unpause a thread?
How can I do it?

Comment: If you set `running` to false you actually don´t pause the execution, your `while` loop will end the the `Thread` has finished it´s execution. Sidenode: please follow the java naming convention and start classnames with uppercase letters.

Comment: so i just have to create a new thread for the same class?

Comment: @DanyLavrov See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37565875/889583) to another, similar question.  I've just posted it and based it on your code here.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (running){
            .
            .  more code
            .
        }
```

so when `running` is false, your `run()` method will *exit* and your thread will be no more.

[Here's an example of how to do what you want](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_control.htm), using `wait()`/`notify()`

Comment: Your thread is already terminated

Comment: i only have one thread. if ill make it wait, which thread will use the notify method?

Comment: You have 2 threads, don't you ? This one and the one that instantiated and ran this thread

Comment: how do i get an instance of the thread of the main method? how do i declare it? i have tried `thread.wait();` but i am getting an error.