# Is there a good solution for a threaded application that can be paused and unpaused externally in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with figuring out a good way to write an application that runs on its own thread. One should be able to start and stop it and while its running to pause and unpause.

```
public abstract class Application implements Runnable {

    private Thread runningThread;
    private volatile boolean isRunning;
    private volatile boolean isPaused;

    public Application() {
        serverThread = null;
        isRunning = false;
        isPaused = false;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(!isRunning) {
            isRunning = true;
            serverThread = new Thread(this);
            serverThread.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(isRunning) {
            isRunning = false;
            try {
                serverThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pause() {
        if(isRunning && !isPaused) {
            isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void unpause() {
        if(isRunning && isPaused) {
            isPaused = false;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void setUp();

    protected abstract void update();

    protected abstract void cleanUp();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setUp();
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!isPaused) {
                update();
            }
        }
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

The worst thing is, that it can be very difficult to propperly debug a program running on a different thread

Comment: You may be able to find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758346/how-pause-and-then-resume-a-thread

Comment: That's why you can attach a debugger to a JVM. All popular IDE's support debugging Java applications, and inside the debugger you can set breakpoints, pause a thread, step through the code, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a debugger such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, which have built-in functionality to set breakpoints, which then pause execution of the application while you inspect variables, etc.