# Thread.start() throwing exception after Thread.isAlive() check

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting into multithreading in Java, and I ran into an odd problem.

When I try to start a new thread with my scheduler using `Thread.start()`, I learned that we need a `Thread.isAlive()` check because starting and resuming take different processes. however, with this code showing the check and `start()`:

```
if ( current.isAlive( ) )
     current.setPriority( 4 );
else {
     // Spawn must be controlled by Scheduler
     // Scheduler must start a new thread
     current.start( );
     current.setPriority( 4 );
}
```

where current is guaranteed to be a valid thread. I end up with this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:790)
        at Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:152)
```

Which is why I think it's a problem of calling `start()` when it's not supposed to . However, to all appearances, it shouldn't be calling `start()` except when the thread is not alive.

Thus, my question is two-fold:

1. Is there something wrong with the above code that allows the second block to run if a thread is already started, and
2. What other things could be going wrong that would throw that exception? I see the same exception thrown in `setDaemon()`, however I'm not calling that, so that should be irrelevant.

Comment: You learnt wrong. `isAlive()` tells you whether it has been started and hasn't finished yet. It doesn't tell you whether or not you can call `start()`. You can't reuse `Thread` objects, and specifically you can't call `start()` on them twice. And there is no such thing as 'resuming' a thread.

Comment: The [start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) method "Throws:
IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started."

Comment: And you can only call `setPriority(4);` if the Thread has not been started yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) has a [`State`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html), retrievable by calling [`getState()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState--). The javadoc of `State` shows:

> A thread state. A thread can be in one of the following states:
>
> - `NEW`
>       A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
> - `RUNNABLE`
>       A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
> - `BLOCKED`
>       A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
> - `WAITING`
>       A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
> - `TIMED_WAITING`
>       A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
> - `TERMINATED`
>       A thread that has exited is in this state.
>
> A thread can be in only one state at a given point in time. These states are virtual machine states which do not reflect any operating system thread states.

When you call [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--), the thread leaves the `NEW` state, and will never have that state ever again. Javadoc of `start()` says:

> Throws `IllegalThreadStateException` if the thread was already started.

That means if the state is not `NEW`.

However, javadoc of [`isAlive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--) says:

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Which means that the thread is not `NEW` (has been started) and not `TERMINATED` (has not yet died)

As you can see, `isAlive()` will return false for `TERMINATED`, even though `TERMINATED` is not a valid state for starting the thread.

If you need to know if you *can* start the thread, check the state:

```
if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
    thread.start();
    // Ok, the thread is now beginning to work on it
} else if (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
    // Yay, the thread is working on it
} else {
    // Oops, what happened???
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that you cannot "reuse" `Thread` instances so you cannot call `start` method on the same instance of `Thread` more than once. From [`Thread:::isAlive`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive()) docs :

> Tests if this thread is alive. **A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.**

So you can fall into your `else` condition if your `Thread` was already started and died (and also when it has not been started yet). And you will get an exception in case you try to start it once again because `IllegalThreadStateException` is thrown if you try to do it. From the docs of [`Thread::start`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>
> Throws:
> `IllegalThreadStateException` - if the thread was already started.

If you would like to pause/resume threads you can do it by using `wait`/`notifyAll` in a correct manner - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758346/how-pause-and-then-resume-a-thread).